# C++ Function to swap pointers works within the scope

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a C++ function that checks and swaps pointer data. My problem is that once the variables go into the function it works properly with no issues, but whenever I return from the function it seems as if it was never entered as the vales still hold the same information from before entering the function.

Below is a code snippet.

```
bool Swap(int* pComp, int* pNew)
    {
        pComp = pNew;
        return true;
    }
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: This doesn't, in any sense, swap two pointers.

Comment: I know I'm not good with names, but I just want to make one pointer equal the other for now.

Comment: Then it should be called Assign instead of Swap.

Comment: @Seb You kept the question title as "swap", though.

Comment: @Seb: He was being facetious. He's saying your attempt is only assignment and not a swap. You should leave your question as-is because you want to swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function doesn't do anything, as it only affects the local pointer variables that exist within function scope.  If you're trying to swap two pointers, you would have to do:

```
Swap(int** pComp, int** pNew){
   int* tmp;
   tmp = *pComp;
   *pComp = *pNew;
   *pNew = tmp;
}
```

Comment: This is assignment, not a swap.

Comment: @Oli, I'm assuming it will be called with Swap(&p1, &p2), in which case the pointers will be swapped

Comment: @TJD: Yes, but it still won't swap anything; you have a single assignment!

Comment: @Oli, got it, I was only fixing half the problem :)  Editing to fix it

Comment: This worked well. Though if C/C++ passes parameters by value, then why would this work?

Comment: @Seb: Please don't use this answer, use Oli's. We have standard functions for a reason.

Comment: @TJD: `Swap(0, 0);` is completely valid (you used pointers and null is a valid pointer value), yet your function produces undefined behavior with valid arguments. That's no good. There's no reason to rewrite this, just use `std::swap`.

Comment: @Seb, yes C passes by value, but the way to effectively get pass by reference is to pass a pointer and dereference in the function.  If you wanted to pass ints by reference, you pass *int.  In your case you wanted to pass *ints by reference, so you pass **int.

Comment: @GMan, I agree and would ust std::swap.  My answer was trying to explain the conceptual errors in the submitted question.  But it is better to use standard solution.

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::swap(pComp, pNew);
```

Comment: Or if you want to swap the pointed-to values: `std::swap(*pComp,*pNew)`

Comment: @bames53: If you want to swap the pointed-to-values use `std::iter_swap(pComp, pNew);`

Answer (score 1):

First, your code does not swap pointers: all it does is assigning the value of pNew to pComp. The reason the program is not doing what you expect is that in C and C++ parameters are passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are Seb:

```
bool Swap(int*& pComp, int*& pNew)
    {
        int* t = pComp;
        pComp = pNew;
        pNew = t;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that C++ is *pass-by-value*.  Try this instead:

```
bool Swap(int *&pComp, int *&pNew)
{
    int *temp = pComp;
    pComp = pNew;
    pNew = temp;
    return true;
}
```

C++ was passing a copy of the pointers to your `Swap` function.

Comment: Whoops! You have to swap your pointers: `*&` instead of `&*`. But as Oli said, it still doesn't swap anything, it just copies `pNew` to `pComp`.

Comment: <s>Pointers to references are not allowed. A reference to a pointer is declared like so: `int *&p`.</s> _edit: variable declarations have been fixed now._ `pComp = pNew` still doesn't 'swap' anything, only assigns `pNew` to `pComp`.

Comment: So even though they were pointers it still passed in a copy of the pointers itself?

Comment: @Seb: Yes; that's always the rule.  The arguments are passed by value, which means that they're copied.

Comment: @bames53 Right.  I accidentally mixed up the order of `*` and `&`.  It should swap them now.